# Executing commands over SSH

Tags: command-line, ssh, remote

I am trying to run commands remotely via SSH using the following syntax:

```
ssh user@host "ps -eaf"
```

This has normally worked in the past, however in this case I keep getting the SCP Usage Returned.

```
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Uhm... it tells you the usage of scp? Are you sure you wrote everything correctly? The command is fine and should work.

Comment: Its so strange! Yeah every-time it returns the usage of SCP. I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Does it return the same if you just do `ssh gibberish` or, on the host machine `ps -eaf` ? Check your `.bashrc`, there might be a clue in there.

Comment: `ssh is /usr/bin/ssh` It appears though its running scp on every remote command, I add -x and it returned unknown option. So I added a SCP option and it returns

Comment: `option requires an argument -- F
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q cipher | cipher-auth | mac | kex | key]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]`

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is happening here - Your remote machine is actually not having ps point towards ps but rather being either an alias for some scp command or the ps is a link towards scp. Check this please.

Comment: Other things to check might be an inappropriate `ProxyCommand` setting in your local `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, or a `ForceCommand` setting in the remote server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: Checked them, They look okay. Its doing with all commands I enter, not just ps -eaf :/

Comment: You noted above that `ssh is /usr/bin/ssh` - but did you check what `/usr/bin/ssh` actually is? Did the binary itself get overwritten with `scp`? For example, what do `/usr/bin/ssh -v` and `ls -li /usr/bin/{ssh,scp}` say?

Comment: /usr/bin/ssh returns the SSH usage and when running that with no command at the end takes me to the server :/

Comment: After checking the /etc/passwd file, I can see root is using /usr/local/bin/rootsh. When I change this to bash it works! Now I need to figure out why it wont work with rootsh

Comment: did you figure out what the problem is with rootsh ? (I see the same symptom :/)

Answer (score 0):

/etc/passwd was pointing to /user/local/bin/rootsh instead of /bin/bash